# Get element by id using special characters with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am new to jQuery, I need to get the element value from this input field

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="preventSomeKeys(event)" onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" name="fee_ctv_omp_percent" id="fee_ctv['omp_percent']" value="0.00" class="w-100" step="0.01" style="border:none;">
```

as you can see the id contains special chars.

I write this code,

```
var test2 = $("#fee_ctv['omp_percent']");
```

and this is the results:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #fee_ctv['omp_percent']
```

[image]

Is their a way to get the element by id in this scenario?

Comment: Why does that ID contain those characters? That seems a little sketchy... It's not even HTML-compliant.

Comment: it worked this is the code, and the html worked, this is php blade

Comment: Try without single quotes `var test2 = $("#fee_ctv[omp_percent]");`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var test2 = $("#fee_ctv\\['omp_percent\\']");
```

For more info check https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: sorry no           var test3 = $("#fee_ctv\\['omp_percent\\']").val();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape selector:
`$.escapeSelector("fee_ctv['omp_percent']")`

and put it in your js like this:

```js
var test2 = $(`#${$.escapeSelector("fee_ctv['omp_percent']")}`);
```

[working codepen](https://codepen.io/jeroenverfaillie/pen/eYMoOLv)

This way, you don't have to manually escape every entry.
[link to docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

Comment: sorry not working  var test5 = $(`#${$.escapeSelector("fee_ctv['omp_percent']")}`).val();                   Uncaught TypeError: $.escapeSelector is not a function

Comment: I've added a codepen to proof that it does work. Don't forget the backticks (`) ! this is not the same as quotes

Comment: If you're using a version of jquery < 3.0 it won't work, but that version is from 2016. Either update or manually escape